# How to refuse unauthenticated connections to mongodb

Tags: mongodb, authentication, connection

So I've managed to get mongodb up and running, having added an super admin user in the admin db and a local admin user in my test table. I've started mongod with

```
mongod --dbpath ./ --auth
```

However if I run

```
mongo
```

from the terminal, I can't perform any modification or reading, but I still seem to be able to sniff databases using

```
use <DBNAME>
```

Is there a way I can completely refuse a connection to the mongod instance if a username and password are not provided?

Comment: `use <DBNAME>` lets you select any database name whether or not it already exits (or is authenticated).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's a misconception here, `use <dbname>` will work whether a database exists or not, there is no information leak since they can't run `show databases` or `show collections` to confirm something is actually there (because they do not have sufficient permissions).  A non-authenticated session is no better than a raw TCP socket, it just looks like more because you are using the `mongo shell` as a client (you can run `mongo --nodb` too and do things but that does not mean that anything is compromised, in that scenario there isn't even a connection to a database).

So, what you are asking for is a way to refuse connections before they make a TCP connection.  However, you have to first make that TCP connection before you actually can authenticate (otherwise how do you talk to the database to authenticate?) so that really doesn't make a lot of sense when you consider how a distributed database works.

If you want to refuse connections except from trusted IP addresses and lock things down etc. then that is generally a good idea but it's done outside the database, in `iptables` or your firewall of choice.